# Есть ли ленивые регулярные выражения в JS

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть два блока, идущих друг за другом:

```
[BLOCK]12345[/BLOCK][BLOCK]543]21[/BLOCK]
```

Как мне регулярным выражением вытащить их по-очереди, чтобы перебрать в цикле?
Такой вариант не работает, ищется весь текст целиком:

```
/(\[BLOCK\].+\[\/BLOCK\])+?/mi
```

Comment: Подойдет? `/(\[BLOCK\].+?\[\/BLOCK\])/gim`

Comment: `/(?<=\[BLOCK]).*?(?=\[\/BLOCK])/m`

Answer (score 3):

Метод [`.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) при использовании флага `g` сохраняет позицию найденного совпадения в объекте регулярного выражения и при следующем запуске начинает с нее, а не с начала строки.

Так же стоит поправить само выражение добавив `?` после `+` - это позволит остановиться при первом появлении `[/BLOCK]`, а так же, если нужен текст внутри то стоит группировать именно его, без самих тегов, в итоге регулярное выражение может принять вид:

```
 /\[BLOCK\](.+?)\[\/BLOCK\]/mig
```

Результатом `.exec` является массив, в котором нулевой элемент - совпавшая подстрока, а последующие элементы соответствуют группировкам.

В случае, если совпадение не найдено будет возвращен `null`

Пример:

```js
var str = '[BLOCK]12345[/BLOCK][BLOCK]543]21[/BLOCK]';

var reg = /\[BLOCK\](.+?)\[\/BLOCK\]/mig;

for (var res = reg.exec(str); res; res = reg.exec(str)) {
  console.log(`match: '${res[0]}', text: '${res[1]}'`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ленивый режим работы квантификаторов – противоположность жадному, он означает «повторять минимальное количество раз».

Его можно включить, если поставить знак вопроса '?' после квантификатора, так что он станет таким: *? или +? или даже ?? для '?'.

Чтобы не возникло путаницы – важно понимать: обычно ? сам является квантификатором (ноль или один). Но если он стоит после другого квантификатора (или даже после себя), то обретает другой смысл – в этом случае он меняет режим его работы на ленивый.

https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-greedy-and-lazy